# Matplotlib FuncAnimation frame not rendering when a new artist added

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am making an animation in Matplotlib where new artists (specifically patches) are added every few frames, but when I run it, every frame in which a new artist is added is completely blank. I know there is some issue with the blitting since it works when I turn that off, but I need it on. I return every shape that is created or modified in each frame, just like the documentation requires. I am using the MacOSX backend.

My code looks similar to this:

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
circles = []

def update(i):
    if not i % 10:
        new_circle = plt.Circle((random(), random()), 0.05, color='black')
        axe.add_patch(new_circle)
        circles.append(new_circle)

    for circle in circles:
        circle.center = (random(), random())

    return circles

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=60, interval=1000/30, repeat=False, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code seem to work as expected for me. I am using Python 3.7.4, matplotlib v.3.1.3, Jupyter notebook 6.0.3 (with the notebook backend). I cannot try the MacOS backend atm.

Comment: `add_patch` may cause an update of the axis extents so that may be the reason your running into conflicts when blitting. Try to use `add_artist` instead (which does not have that side effect).

Comment: It's a bit hard to see the error with the frame rate of 30 I have set, but it is consistently present with the MacOSX backend. Using add_artist produces the same issue. However, switching to a different backend (TkAgg in my case) fixed the problem. I'll add this bug to the github page for matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with matplotlib in the MacOSX backend, so the solution is just to work around it by using a different backend or not blitting if possible.